# solr - fuzzy search not returning any results for longer terms

Tags: solr

If I do `q=filling~`, results are returned, but if I do for example `q=prefabricated~` or another longer word, 0 results are returned. Funny thing is in my analysis, the query is showing as matching. What could be the reason?

My schema:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

request handler parameters:

```
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <int name="rows">40</int>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">parent_and_self_description details^0.0001 info^0.0001 code^10000</str>
      <str name="pf">parent_and_self_description^100 details^10 info^10</str>
      <int name="ps">100</int>
      <str name="fl">code type description min_fee max_fee lab_costs material_expenses independent_consideration parent_code parent_description grandparent_code grandparent_description details info code_highlighted</str>
      <str name="hl">on</str>
      <str name="hl.fl">description parent_description grandparent_description details info code</str>
      <str name="hl.method">unified</str>
      <int name="hl.fragsize">10</int>
      <str name="hl.tag.pre">&lt;strong&gt;</str>
      <str name="hl.tag.post">&lt;/strong&gt;</str>
      <str name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">false</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the processing of your token makes it far shorter, and that makes the edit distance from your original text too great to make it a hit

Comment: @MatsLindh That must be it! "impkant~" returns results for implant, but "felling" doesn't return results for "filling". It must have to do with the stemming. How do I fix it?

Comment: Query against a field that doesn't have stemming enabled. Use `copyField` to index the same content into both fields, but then process it differently based on the field

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you. I read your other posts, and am going to try spellcheck ("did you mean...") instead.